# Database table with nullable foreign key

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, audit-trail

I am creating a new database design for my website. There are two types of users in my database. So I have **user_t** and it is associated with **client_t**. One user can have multiple clients. Now I have **app_t**. One client can have more than one application.

This **app_t** can be updated by both client and user. I am creating audit trial table for **app_t** where I don’t want to store name in **updated_by** because it might change. Instead I want to have **client_id** and **user_id** as column. In this case when client updates the table **user_id** column will be null and when user updates the table **client_id** will be null. Both of these ids are foreign keys which is referencing primary key columns of respective tables. Is it okay to have such null values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can a user or a client ever be deleted?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel No we never delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it okay to have such null values?

This is subjective. The question is: can you work with it? Probably - Yes. But can it guarantee integrity? No.

So what can go wrong? You can set both foreign keys or you can keep both NULL - And the DB will not complain. In neither case you know, who has updated the item.

Another approach would be to always set `user_id` (NOT NULL) and let `client_id` be optional. If the `client_id` is NULL, you know - it's updated by the user. If it's not NULL, then you know - it's updated by the client.

You can then retrieve the name with:

```
select at.*, coalesce(c.name, u.name) as updated_by
from app_audit at
join user_t u        on u.id = at.user_id
left join client_t c on c.id = at.client_id
```

But things still can go wrong. You could save an ID of a client who is not "owner" of the app. The same applies to `user_id`. Due to the design (audit-trail -> app -> client -> user) both `client_id` and `user_id` are functionally dependent on `app_id`. So actually all you need is `app_id` as foreign key and a boolean flag which tells you, if it's updated by user or client. Then you would retrieve the data with:

```
select at.*, coalesce(u.name, c.name) as updated_by
from app_audit at
join app_t a       on a.id = at.app_id
join client_t c    on c.id = a.client_id
left join user_t u on u.id = c.user_id  and a.updatet_by_user = 1
```

Regarding your comment:

I don't believe in such thing like "best approach" or "best practice", when a problem is "complex enough". The question is then - *Best* for what? Usually you have multiple objectives like *clearness*, *simplicity*, *usability*, *flexibility*, *reliability*, *performance* and probably some more. The "best approach" for flexibility might be a nightmare for performance and vice versa.

A more widely used term is "*good practice*". And *database normalization* is considered to be *good practice*. Adding `user_id` and `client_id` introduces *functionally dependencies* on a non [*candidate key*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key), which violates [*3NF*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

On the other side, without those columns you need one more JOIN in your SELECT queries. But as long as it is not significant, I wouldn't care much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PaulSpiegel . Sorry for the late reply. We had the same Idea of having only the `app_id` association and then have a flag to denote whether it is client or user. But we were not sure whether it is the best practice because we are new to database designs. If you really feel, it is the best approach, I will go ahead and mark it as answered.

Comment: @sureshbabu My response was too long for a comment - so i've updated the answer.

Comment: Can you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501603/how-to-add-indexing-for-a-search-based-on-multiple-columns-in-mysql-table

Comment: If it is not going to guarantee integrity, why bother declaring the FK??