# How to add indexing for a search based on multiple columns in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am adding a search button with the suggestions displayed while we type on it similar to google and I need to search multiple columns in a single table. How to add indexing for that columns?

I have two tables in my application named as `Employer` and `Employee`.
I want to add a search box so that the Employer can search employees of only his organisation based on their name or email or phone number. When the employers types on the search box I need to show the suggestions below. For Ex. when employer types **Jo** on the text box, I will show suggestions as

1. Jon, jon@gmail.com, 12345
2. Bobby, jon-bobby@gmail.com, 9876
3. .....

The Employee table has columns `id, name, email, phone, employer_id fk references Employer` table.

What I think the query might be is

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee 
where employer_id = 1 
and LOWER(name) like '%jo%' 
or LOWER(email) like '%jo%' 
or LOWER(phone) like '%jo%'
```

I want to know whether this is a valid query to use. I am not sure about its performance. Also I am not sure how to add index to this table in this particular use case.

I would really appreciate your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Indexes are added to the Database Schema not in the application code

Comment: If you are going to use AND and OR in one query you need to bracket the criteria so that the AND and OR do not get confused

Comment: `where employer_id = 1 
and (LOWER(name) like '%jo%' 
or LOWER(email) like '%jo%' 
or LOWER(phone) like '%jo%')`

Comment: You should search for "fulltext index". But it might not help in this case, since you cannot use multiple indexes for one table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think none of your comments answer my question. Also I have clearly mentioned adding index on the table which means the database not application code.

Comment: Is this [index Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html) any use to you?

Comment: I got an answer here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233907/how-to-add-indexing-for-a-search-based-on-multiple-columns-in-mysql-table